# Render function in React called after ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

I have a react component which includes a styled component with a reference (innerRef). According to react lifecycle, the function "ComponentDidMount" executed after rendering the components,  therefore the function in the first block supposed to be executed after the rendering function. 
**As you can see in the console, first ComponentDidMount is called and after that, the rendering function.**

ComponentDidMount -

```
async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount Called in " + new Date().toLocaleString());
}
```

Render -

```
return (
      <div>
        <StyledComponent innerRef={this.selectedElement} id={elementId}/>
        {console.log("Render function Called in " + new Date().toLocaleString())}
      </div>
    );
```

Console [image: difference in time]

Comment: all you've shown us is two function snippets with no context.  What is "Mon container"?  What is "Mon video container"?  Which components have the above render and componentDidMount methods?  Are they even the same component?  What is the renderiing tree (which components render which children)?  Post a more complete code example.